# Hibernate JPA Criteria Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I need to query an object that contains a list.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userAccount")
public class UserAccounts implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(name = "hash", nullable = false, length = 60)
private String hash;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleID"))
private List<Role> roles;

@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Status status;

//getters and setters
}
```

I need to get objects that contains role "ROLE_USER".
how can I achieve that using CriteriaBuilder?

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserAccounts> cq = cb.createQuery(UserAccounts.class);
    Root<UserAccounts> ua = cq.from(UserAccounts.class);
```

What Should I put here?

```
//      cq.where(cb.and(cq.equals(ua.get("roles")),
//      cq.equals(ua.get("status"), Status.ACTIVE)));
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent JPQL could be like this

```
SELECT ua FROM UserAccount ua JOIN ua.roles r WHERE r.name = :roleName
```

so the Criteria would be something like

```
Join<UserAccounts, Role> roleRoot = ua.join(UserAccounts_.roles);
roleRoot.alias("r");
ParameterExpression<String> param = qb.parameter(String.class);
cq.where(roleRoot.get(Role_.name).equals(param));
```

Comment: Hi, using ua.join(UserAccounts_.roles); requires me to change roles to public. i don't think i should change that to public though.

Comment: No it doesn't require public. This is the static metamodel class! You can use the equivalent String based getter if you insist on using Strings

Comment: Finally got it to work. turns out I was mising Hibernate-metamodel-generator.jar. Thank You So Much!